# Check if all elements of array includes inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if all of the audio file names in `unorderedPhrases` array exist in the `result` array that contains the URLs. if there are all exist return `true` and if-else return `false`.

Here is what I've tried. I don't know why it returns `false` all the times!?

```js
let result = [

  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/i was sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to earth.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to protect you.mp3",

];

const unorderedPhrases = [

    'i was sent',
    'to earth',
    'to protect you'

];

function checkResults(){
 
    return unorderedPhrases.every(r=> result.includes(r));

 
}

console.log(checkResults())
```

The above code should return true because all the audio files in `unorderedPhrases` exist in the `result` array.

if we have this array then it should return `false` because there is a item in `unorderedPhrases` that doesn't exist in `result` :

```
let result = [
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/i was sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to earth.mp3",
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ignore the folder structure and only consider what comes at the very end, you can remove the folder part from each `result` item first, turning it into another array, then when iterating over the phrases, check if the array without the folder part includes the phrase plus `.mp3`:

```js
let result = [
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/i was sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to earth.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to protect you.mp3",
];

const resultWithoutFolders = result.map(str => str.split('/').pop());

const unorderedPhrases = [
  'i was sent',
  'to earth',
  'to protect you'
];

function checkResults() {
  return unorderedPhrases.every(
    phrase => resultWithoutFolders.includes(phrase + '.mp3')
  );
}

console.log(checkResults())
```

Comment: for `const unorderedPhrases = [

    'i was sent',
    'to earth',


];` it returns true!

Comment: Both of those exist in one of the `result` array items, so it returns `true`. *I want to check if all of the audio file names in unorderedPhrases array exist in the result array that contains the URLs* If you added a phrase that *didn't* exist in any of the `result` strings, like `foo`, it'd return `false`

Comment: Your example result conflicts with the problem description, can you edit the question to clarify the logic you want?

Comment: Ok for `let result = [
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/i was sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to earth.mp3",
];` it returns true also! and it shouldn't.

Comment: Why? All of the phrases *are* included in one of the substrings there. `i was sent` is present in the first item, and `to earth` is also present in the first item

Comment: Still doesn't make sense - all of the elements in `unorderedPhrases` **do** exist somewhere in the `result` array. Actually, each phrase exists in *every* element of the `result` array. Why'd you want to return `false` if every string you're searching for exists in every string of the `result` array?

Comment: Yeah it gets complicated when I want to put it into words. All of the elements in `unorderedPhrases` do exist somewhere in the `result` array except one: `to protect you`

Comment: And this exception should return a `false`

Comment: Yes it does exist: `unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/` is present in each of the `result` items, which contains `to protect you`

Comment: So I need a substring here?! what do you recommend... I haven't seen that...

Comment: What do you mean? Your problem is still quite unclear. The `to protect you` **does** exist in every `result` string, why would you want it to be `false` if it **does actually** exist in `result`?

Comment: For example, `"https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/i was sent.mp3".includes('to protect you')` return `true` as expected, because `to protect you` exists in the larger string

Comment: I think if we change your code to resultStr => resultStr.includes(`/${phrase}.mp3`) it may solve the problem.

Comment: **What** is the problem? What is the logic you're looking for? Like I just said, `to protect you` exists in the `result` array, so why would you not want it to be found?

Comment: Oh, this is the first time you mentioned that. Probably best to edit the question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

It returns false because `result` is a 2D array. That means your `result` has 3 elements, which are those 3 strings, and each string is an array consisting of characters.

EDIT: Sorry for the mis-assumption. T.J. Crowder has pointed out for me. It's not an 2D array. The strings act like array too. So it can be accessed like a 2D array

This would be a more correct snippet:

```js
let result = [

  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/i was sent.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to earth.mp3",
  "https://example.com/test/unordered/i was sent to earth to protect you_A/to protect you.mp3",

];

const unorderedPhrases = [

    'i was sent',
    'to earth',
    'to protect you'

];

function checkResults(){
 
    return unorderedPhrases.every(r => result[0].includes(r))

 
}

console.log(checkResults())
```

If you want to check all the 3 strings in `result` you have to loop over it. At each time, check the `unorderedPhrases` like above

Comment: *"It returns false because `result` is a 2D array."* No, it isn't. It's a 1D array. An array of strings.

Comment: My bad for that. Strings are also array. I forgot

Comment: Strings aren't arrays.

Comment: My trivial experience. It acts like arrays, not arrays. Thanks T.J Crowder